# Deleting Li doesnot work for dynamic li

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my script in which I am creating li onclick of a button but the issue is the li's which are created after clicking the add button doesnot remove when i click the remove button. Kindly let me know what I did wrong

```
   <p>
      <ul class="">
      <li>Folder Name : <input type='text' class='fname' value='' required='required' /> <input type='button' class='liDelete'  value='- Remove' /></li>
      </ul>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="button" name="butadd" id="butadd" value="+ Add New" />
      </p>

    $(document).ready(function () {


            $('.liDelete').click(function () {
        li = $(this).parent();
        li.remove();
    });


        $("#butadd").click(function () {
            $("ul").append("<li>Folder Name : <input type='text' class='fname' value='' required='required' /> <input type='button' class='liDelete'  value='- Remove' /></li>");

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `.on` event.

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/mT5vw/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.liDelete', function () {
        li = $(this).parent();
        li.remove();
    });
    $("#butadd").click(function () {
        $("ul").append("<li>Folder Name : <input type='text' class='fname' value='' required='required' /> <input type='button' class='liDelete'  value='- Remove' /></li>");
    });
});
```

Comment: hey I am running `$('#folders li').each(function (e)` function too and I am wondering how to remove the active li in that case?

Comment: @user3027531 I reckon you found the solution already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453953/remove-respective-li-from-all `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) since when the handler is registered the dynamic elements does not exists.

```
 $('ul').on('click', '.liDelete', function () {
     var li = $(this).parent();
     li.remove();
 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HG5DW/)