# Remove Respective Li from all

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my fiddle in which when user click on all delete then on foreach for LI function. I want to remove those lis which contains name like `abc,def,ghk` in their input field . I just want to know how to check that the active li  on foreach loop contains the certain value that matches it `input field` value or not so i'll stop to remove it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mT5vw/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.liDelete', function () {
        li = $(this).parent();
        li.remove();
    });
    $("#butadd").click(function () {
        $("ul").append("<li>Folder Name : <input type='text' class='fname' value='' required='required' /> <input type='button' class='liDelete'  value='- Remove' /></li>");
    });
});

function alldelete() {
    $('#folder li').each(function (e) {});
}
```

Comment: What is "a name like `abc,def,ghk`"? Is that each name that consists of three consecutive characters, each name that consists of 3 comma separated words, each name that consists of 3 comma separate words of 3 consecutive characters each, ...?

Comment: @Confusion `abc` is the dummy name with which I'll check the value of the input box of each LI that either it matches with it or not?

Comment: Do you whant to remove duplicates? I don't really understand?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the `li` that the input contains a value like `ABC` try:

```
$('#removeAll').click(function(){
    $('#folder li input[type="text"]').each(function () {   
       if ($(this).val() === "abc") {
           $(this).parent().remove();
        }
    });
```

here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NH5Lc/) only write `abc` in the `input` and before press remove all.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mT5vw/3/

If this is what you what it can be achieved by, removing all elements from the  tag and then reinserting one empty row.

js:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


    $(document).on('click', '.liDelete',function() {
        li = $(this).parent();
        li.remove();
    });


    $("#butadd").click(function () {
        $("ul").append("<li>Folder Name : <input type='text' class='fname' value='' required='required' /> <input type='button' class='liDelete'  value='- Remove' /></li>");

    });

    $("#deleteall").click(function(){
        $('#folder').html("<li>Folder Name : <input type='text' class='fname' value='' required='required' /> <input type='button' class='liDelete' value='- Remove' /></li>");
    });
});
```